# How to set a custom login processing page for spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

i was having problem getting spring security to process the login from the controller i have defined in a class namely

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

I did some googling and found that spring takes the default login processng page as `/j_spring_security_check`

So how can i make spring do the login processing from the controller i have defined.

I have this in my security.config file

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

     try {
        http
         .csrf().disable()
         .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
         .antMatchers("/settings/api/**").permitAll()
         .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
         .formLogin()
         .loginPage("/login").permitAll()

         .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("sadhiasdniaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa:");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

i want spring to use this controller to process the login but it isn't using it

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    System.out.println("\n\n\n*******hello11111111111111********      " + request.getSession().getAttribute("userLoginStatus"));
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    boolean f = false;
    f = customAuthenticationProvider.verifyUser(username,password,request);
    if(f == false) 
        return "loginError";
    else
        return "index";
}
```

Comment: Config looks good. What is your problem?

Comment: Why? You should really integrate with Spring Security not work around it (which is what you are doing right now).

Comment: Well yeah but still , there must be some way to do this . i did try adding     .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
to the security config file and still no good luck

Comment: No there isn't. The `loginProcessingUrl` is to configure the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and not your own controller. Why do you need your own controller, as stated you really should be integrating with Spring security, you are working around it. Either use it or not...

Answer (score 0):

Make your controller a [custom authentication provider](https://danielkaes.wordpress.com/2013/02/20/custom-authentication-provider-in-spring/) and wire it up under the <authentication manager/> in your Spring security.xml file.  See [here](https://github.com/gmazza/tightblog/blob/trunk/app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/security.xml) for an example of such a configuration.